# How do I select multiple classes incremented by 1 and their matching children?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple containers that I need to animate.
Basically: you click on class: box-*n* (e.g. box-1) and you slideToggle: box-child-*n* (e.g. box-child-1).
Instead of a click function for every box-*n* to toggle box-child-*n*, I want a simple line of code that matches box-*n* with its children class.

html:

```
<div class="box-1">Some clickable container</div>
<div class="box-child-1">This should toggle when box-1 is clicked</div>

<div class="box-2">Some clickable container</div>
<div class="box-child-2">This should toggle when box-2 is clicked</div>

Et cetera...
```

current jquery:

```
$('.box-1').click(function() { $('.box-child-1').slideToggle() });
$('.box-2').click(function() { $('.box-child-2').slideToggle() });
```

Sort of desired jquery (allInt function is made up.):

```
var $n = allInt();

$('.box-' + n).click(function() {
    $('.box-child-' + _n).slidetoggle() // local variable to inter alia .box-1
})
```

I can't seem to think of any solution, so I am asking for help once again.
I appreciate every suggestion you folks give me!

Comment: Why are you using `class` rather than `id` (given that you seem to be assigning unique classes)?

Comment: That is irrelevant since an id would defeat the purpose of having as little code as possible to achieve said goal. I simply want a line that states that when you click box-*n* you will slideToggle its child box-child-*n*. edit: on second thought - it depends on the javascript code.

Comment: The solutions provided so far would work with `id` or `class`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it that allows for the elements to have other classes besides the ones that you're using to pair them up:

```
$('div[class*="box-"]').click(function() {
    var c = this.className.match(/\bbox-\d+\b/);
    if (c)
        $('div.' + c[0].replace(/-/, '-child-')).slideToggle();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6xM47/

That is, use the [`[name*=value]` attribute contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) to find any divs with a class attribute that has `"box-"` in it somewhere. Then when clicked extract the actual class and check that it matches the `"box-n"` pattern - this allows for multiple (unrelated) classes on the element. If it does match, find the associated `"box-child-n"` element and toggle it.

Having said all that, I'd suggest structuring the markup more like this:

```
<div data-child="box-child-1">Some clickable container</div>
<div class="box-child-1">This should toggle when box-1 is clicked</div>
```

...because then the JS is simple and direct:

```
$('div[data-child]').click(function() {
    $('div.' + $(this).attr('data-child')).slideToggle();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6xM47/1/

Comment: the data-child variant is an interesting one, I'll be using it instead of what I have going. Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

To just answer your question, this will do the trick :

```
$("div[class^='box-']").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('.' + $(this).attr('class').replace('-','-child-') ).slideToggle();

});
```

jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yiernehr/kahXx/).

Anyway i dont think you use a good approach (you may wrap child into parent div or use ids).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, though I will be using the above solution.